# Creating a PostgreSQL SERIAL column using pgAdmin3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.2

When I use pgAdmin3 to create a column of type `serial`, why does it instead create `nextval('prices_id_seq'::regclass)`?

Should we keep this type defined by pgAdmin? Manually create the table with SQL defining `id` column as type `serial` causes the pgAdmin SQL pane to again display it as `nextval('prices_id_seq'::regclass)`.

**pgAdmin SQL Pane**

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('prices_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Comment: This seems more like a feature request for the product in question rather than an actual question. @CraigRinger did a great job of explaining the `::regclass` thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13290020/251174). I suspect that pgAdmin3 is simply being overly verbose.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a pgAdmin feature but that of PostgreSQL.  If you check your table from an other client (eg. psql) you will see the exact same column definition.  Why is it so?

> The data types serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a
>   notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar
>   to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases). In
>   the current implementation, specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname SERIAL
> );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
> );
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
> ```

It is always useful to consult the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

Comment: There's more to it ..

Answer (score 1):

[deszo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40860/3684) is right, of course, but it's ***not the whole story***.

pgAdmin actually reverse engineers the code, and if *all* criteria for a `serial` column are met, a `serial` column is displayed *as such*.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  foo_id serial ...
```

There was a bug in some old version that caused pgAdmin to fail in this respect, but it has long since been fixed. You fail to supply your version of pgAdmin, but I would suggest to try it with the current version. That's 1.16.1 at the time of writing.
http://www.pgadmin.org/